# how to add spinner till content load fully inside dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-spinner

I'm opening my edit form inside dialog box. but when click on edit button first it load empty bo with submit and cancel button and content load after around 3 seconds. How can I load spinner till content load fully inside dialog box?

mycode

```
 $("#userTable").on("click", " .edit-page .myHref", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $link = ($this.attr('href'));
        opendialog($link);
        return false;
    });

    function opendialog($link) {

        var $dialog = $('<div id="dialog_edit"></div>')
            .load($link + ' #content_edit')
            .dialog({
                width: 535,
                resizable: false,
                modal: true,
                position: ['center', 100],
                show: {effect: 'fade', duration: 500},
                autoOpen: false,
                title: "Edit User",
                buttons: [
                    {
                        text: "Update",
                        type: "submit",
                        "class": 'updateButtonClass',
                        click: function () {
                            $('.updateButtonClass').submit();
                            toggleSpinner();
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        text: "Cancel",
                        "class": 'saveButtonClass',
                        click: function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
                ],

            });



        $dialog.ajaxSuccess(function () {


            $("#edit_user select").chosen({
                disable_search: true,
                width: "100%"
            });
            // setTimeout(function(){
            //date-pickers-- Start
            var validCurDate = $('.valid_to').val();
            var activationCurDate = $('.activation_on').val();
            // alert(validCurDate);

            $(".valid_to").datepicker({
                firstDay: 1,
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                minDate: activationCurDate,
                onSelect: function (selected) {
                    $('.activation_on').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', selected);
                }
            });

            $(".activation_on").datepicker({

                firstDay: 1,
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                maxDate: validCurDate,
                onSelect: function (selected) {
                    $('.valid_to').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selected);
                }
            });

            // Clear datepicker Max/Min-Date the field if empty
            $('.valid_to').change(function () {
                $(".activation_on").datepicker('option', 'maxDate', null);
            });
            $('.activation_on').change(function () {
                $(".valid_to").datepicker('option', 'minDate', null);
            });
        })

            $dialog.dialog('open');
```

Comment: How to add a spinner and wait with opening the edit window until it finished loading. So when the box appears it has all the fields visible. pls advice

Comment: @bpedroso can u help me

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).